# How to avoid outOfMemmoryError when store bitmap high quality in sd Card in android

Tags: java, android, stream, android-bitmap

I want to store bitmap in to SD card but when I pick large bitmap I faced "out of memory error" problem.

My code:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);         
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

I read many likely questions but they answers not solve my problem because all of answers says you must save bitmap in low quality.

Pleas don't answer me to reduce quality because I need to store bitmap in high quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the available memory size before loading bitmap, by

```
BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
btmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

then if the memory exceeds, you have to resize the bitmap, finaly set

```
BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    btmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

to load the bitmap. 
For increasing allocated memory, you can use `largeHeap` set to `true` but which just increase the allocated memory,

Sample codeto resize bitmap,

```
public int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Tanks , How can I relate this to My code? How can I use it?

Comment: you have to load bitmap based on the available memory. btmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true; will not load the memory, so that, you can check and resize to find the adjusted size and load the image based on the adjusted size.

Comment: To use this I need instance option likely  `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);` but my bitmap have not any path.I tried to convert bitmap to byteArray which use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(byteArray, options);`  but it too faced outOfMemory problem.I know that I have to use this but I don't Know how?

Comment: FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);  shows you are writing to a file, Am I wrong??!!!

Comment: `FileOutputStream out` be needed to store compressed bitmap to a directory. bm is my input which I want to store in SD card. bm has't any directory because I created it by canvas.